# Enable Data Profiling on Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow, adhoc-queries

Data profiling although present in [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/profiling.html) is not visible in a fresh installation. Is there a way to enable it, or it has been deprecated? Installed version is `apache-airflow==1.10.3` in case it helps.

Answer (score 3):

[Airflow 2 disabled Data Profiling  due to security reasons](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md): (`Breaking changes` section)

> Due to security concerns, the new web server will no longer support the features in the Data Profiling menu of the old UI, including Ad Hoc Query, Charts, and Known Events.

Comment: the hyperlink does not work anymore

Answer (score 2):

Data profile is default UI when install airflow v1.10.3.

If you can not see data profile menu, you might need to double check if 3rd party customized airflow for you.
Airflow use flask as web framework. you can go to the related folder to see if it has been modified.
the configuration file is at [you airflow source code folder]\www\app.py

---

Thanks for vote for the answer.
The default app.py section related to dataprofiling is below:

```
 with app.app_context():
        from airflow.www import views

        admin = Admin(
            app, name='Airflow',
            static_url_path='/admin',
            index_view=views.HomeView(endpoint='', url='/admin', name="DAGs"),
            template_mode='bootstrap3',
        )
        av = admin.add_view
        vs = views
        av(vs.Airflow(name='DAGs', category='DAGs'))

        if not conf.getboolean('core', 'secure_mode'):
            print("create_app", __file__)
            av(vs.QueryView(name='Ad Hoc Query', category="Data Profiling"))
            av(vs.ChartModelView(
                models.Chart, Session, name="Charts", category="Data Profiling"))
        av(vs.KnownEventView(
            models.KnownEvent,
            Session, name="Known Events", category="Data Profiling"))
```

As you can see from above code, it related to secure mode. 
      **if not conf.getboolean('core', 'secure_mode'):**
you might need check you secure mode configuration as well.

Note: pls check if the secure_mode in airflow.cfg is configurated properly.

the data profiling can only be showed in **secure_mode = False.**

```
# If set to False enables some unsecure features like Charts and Ad Hoc Queries.
# In 2.0 will default to True.
secure_mode = False
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case. I have installed it myself. Looked here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/app.py shouldn't there be a appbuilder.add_view(views.SOMETHING, "TOOLS", category="xxx") somewhere in that list?

Comment: thanks for vote my answer. I copied the related code for your reference.

Comment: I added the change in editing. After changing the .cfg file, do I need to do anything else (like propagate the changes to database or something)? I tried + rebooted but the menu is still not visible.

Comment: well, interesting. I think you might need check the airflow.cfg in AIRFLOW_HOME folder, to change the secure_mode to off. I noticed the secure_mode is configured to disable the data profiling purpose.