# How can i access metadata db of GCP Composer Airflow server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I have created one Composer in gcp project. I want to access the Metadatadb of Airflow which runs at background on Cloud SQL.
How can i access that?

Also i want to create one table inside that metadatadb which i will be using to store some data query by one of airflow dag. Is it ok to create any table inside that metadatadb or that metadatadb is only for airflow server use?

Answer (score 1):

You can access Airflow internal DB via UI using *Data Profiling* -> *Ad Hoc Query*

There you can see all the tables with a SQL query like :

```
SHOW tables;
```

I wouldn't recommand creating a new table or manually inserting rows into existing tables thought.

You should also be able to access this DB in your DAGs operators and sensors by using `airflow-db` connexion.

Comment: Thanks @vdolez, can't i directly connect to cloud sql from command line?
Is it secure way to insert or select data from airflow webserver?

Comment: @JosephD I think the SQL DB is hidden in another GCP project owned by Google. What you can do is use the connexion inside a DAG, export it to another DB and then query it from there.

Comment: The Ad-Hoc feature was deprecated in early 1.10 Airflow versions for security reasons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184216/enable-data-profiling-on-apache-airflow

Comment: @Benzi and it doesn't exist anymore in version 2+